# Excel Formula that identify whether a date is in the list of dates

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, formula, countif

I have a list of dates in Excel :

```
22/07/2022, 23/08/2022, 24/09/2022
```

I want to identify whether a specific date (current date) is in the list of dates. (E.g. 24/09/2022)

What formula shall I use ?

I tried  the formula below, but it doesn't work. It gives inaccurate results.

```
(COUNTIF([Future Assumptions].[Dummy Values], Today()) > 0)
```

Note :

`[Future Assumptions].[Dummy Values]` returns a list of dates.

UPDATE 1:

`[Future Assumptions].[Dummy Values]` has values :

```
6/30/2025
12/30/1899
12/30/1899
6/30/2026
12/30/1899
12/30/1899
12/30/1899
3/31/2024
6/30/2026
12/29/1905
12/20/2031
12/30/1899
11/17/2025
12/30/1899
12/30/1899
10/30/2025
12/30/1899
12/30/1899
3/30/2024
5/30/2025
7/14/2028
12/30/1899
12/31/2022
12/30/1899
7/18/2028
1/31/2026
8/14/2025
3/30/2028
12/30/1899
10/30/2025

(COUNTIF([Future Assumptions].[Dummy Values].List(), 12/70/1990) > 0)
```

It always returns `1` even if the value '12/70/1990' is not in the list.

Comment: `[Future Assumptions].[Dummy Values]` must be a **range** containing the dates of interest.

Comment: If `FutureAssumptions` is a table (no spaces allowed) and `Dummy Values` is the header of one of its columns, then in the same worksheet you could use `=COUNTIF(FutureAssumptions[Dummy Values],TODAY())` or `=COUNTIF(FutureAssumptions[Dummy Values],"="&TODAY())` where you could replace the double-quoted equal sign with anything appropriate. Instead of `TODAY()`, you could use a reference to a cell containing a date.

Comment: I would use `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(date, dates, 0))`